Can't Access Ubuntu Remotely Using VPN
I recently lost the ability to remotely access my homelab running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS using a VPN (Wireguard). I'm not aware of any direct changes that would have caused this.
When I am on my home network, I have full access to the device. Once I turn on the VPN, I lose all ability to communicate with my homelab (e.g., can't ping, can't SSH, can't access any internal sites). I have full access to all other devices on my network, including a second Ubuntu box running 22.04.2 LTS.
I've tried disabling UFW, but that didn't help. I've also tried deleting and adding various routing rules, but my Linux networking knowledge isn't the best.
Any help would be much appreciated. For reference, I have included by routing table, but can provide anything else needed.
esalz@1812-homelab:~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.54.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eno2
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
172.18.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-5e173ed27d7f
172.23.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-aedcb6ab613d
172.24.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-97935157e08d
172.29.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-00d8bfef2715
172.30.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br-3a8c573ae61a
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 br-98334e73e724
192.168.54.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno2
192.168.54.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eno2



When the VPN is being used it is normal to not be able to run ssh to access it.

Thanks for the reply. Is there a work around for this? I can SSH or ping any other computer on my network. I can also access any of my internal sites via the IP address (e.g., Home Assistant) for my other Linux box, but I can't access any of my internal sites from the one I'm having issues with (e.g., Frigate). Also, to clarify one point, the VPN is at the router level, so accessing the VPN should give access to my entire network (except the VLANs where I block VPN access).
